# Should an E-commerce Site that is predominantly a B2B site have OAuth?

Tags: forms, registration, b2b

A company that I work at from time to time is looking to add OAuth to their site, and had asked for my recommendation if it's worth the development time and if people would actually use it.

In my opinion since its predominantly a B2B site, a lot of customers will not want to tie their Social accounts to their site.

Is there any research on whether adding OAuth to a B2B E-commerce site has increased sales or new customers in a quantifiable way?

Comment: Hey, Joe. Stack Exchange isn't really a discussion forum, so questions like "what do you think about X" aren't particularly welcome here. Could you please rephrase the question so that there is just 1 correct answer to the problem?

Comment: @dnbrv thanks, I hope this is more direct and leaves only a yes or no answer.

Comment: Yup. That's much better. =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your concerns are why Oauth methods are generally *optional* on sites. See the discussion and answers on the question [Should we restrict signup for a service to Facebook accounts only?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/11965/should-we-restrict-signup-for-a-service-to-facebook-accounts-only).

Oauth should be seen as an option, this allows users *willing to share their info* to sign up super easily, but *forcing it's use* will cause you to lose customers that do not trust you with that info. Additionally they may not trust the Oauth provider with the information they give you.

Note that depending on the Oauth providers you offer, the company may have a company account, such as a company Gmail or Twitter account they can use, so it's not *impossible* for a B2B site to make use of Oauth.

Leaving a standard email/password sign up with the Oauth signup will appease all these issues while still allowing users to use Oath *if they choose to do so*.

Comment: Also, LinkedIn implements OAuth, which is mainly business-oriented.